# simple symmetric encryption algorithm in php

Tags: php, encryption-symmetric

I am looking for simple symmtric algorithm (low on processing power) in php.

An encrypted value will be stored as a session_id on client end. And will have logged in status saved in it.

Also I need to also decrypt it on server side.
Please suggest....

Comment: check the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387755/how-to-generate-unique-order-id-just-to-show-touser-with-actual-order-id

Comment: thanks..this is what i want..I will check on processing power...

Answer (score 1):

The only constraint you've mentioned is low processing impact - but you've provided no details of the strength of the algorithm required.

Also, if the encryption is implemented in PHP, then it will be several orders of magnitude less efficient than native code as provided by the mcrypt extension (and others).

> An encrypted value will be stored as a session_id

Why????

The session id is randomly generated and therefore not predictable / guessable. And sessions provide a mechanism for storing data on the server. If the issue is to maintain secure data outside of the session due to shared hosting constraints, then this is **not** the right way to solve the problem.

There are native PHP implementations of various algorithms, TEA being an obvious choice, and str_rot13() is available even if mcrypt/openssl extensions are unavailable. But I can see no logical application of these methods to **any** problem.

Comment: when i said "session_id" i did not mean the session_id which is used to track user..I just meant login information when i said session_id..Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: If you're just wanting a "remember me" function then use a randomly generated value for the cookie - effectively a long-lived session. If you want to track who is currently logged into your DB then switch to using a DB bound session handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the mcrypt-extension. [there](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php) you go for some simple examples.

It offers you many symmetric encryptions.