# Generating a random and unique string

Tags: php, unique

I need a valid way to get both a *random* and **unique** string, with either a zero (or negligible) chance of a duplicate.

I need characters in the `[0-9A-z]` range.

This is what I have so far:

```
substr(sha1(mt_rand().uniqid()),0,22);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Recent changes to PHP

Since I know this is actually talking about bcrypt and password salting now I can really just point people reading this to functions they should be using instead of manually rolling their own salt system.

Use `password_hash($input, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` to generate a hash suitable to insert into a database. This will fetch the salt for you.

Insertion:

```
$hash = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ["cost" => 16]);
DB::table("users")->insert(["username" => $user, "password" => $hash]);
// or whatever database method you use to insert data
```

Verification:

```
$hash = DB::table("users")->fetchByName($username)->select("password");
$input = $_POST["password"];

$verified = password_verify($input, $hash); // true if the password matches
```

In versions before PHP 5.5, use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat as a drop-in<sup>1</sup>

---

When randomly generating a salt, the odds of a collision are

```
1 / [number of possible letters/numbers] ** [length]
```

Which for a 22-character string are impossibly low (well, not *impossibly*, but ***negligibly***)

```
1 / (22 ** 60) = 1 / (3.51043 x 10**80)
```

See? ***tiny***.

---

## Mathematical Fallacy

If you need a truly random string (note: these strings are just a line of numbers mapped to letters), then you're a little out of luck.
What you're looking for is a CSPRNG (Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator). No need for uniqueness.

As ***@Guarav*** pointed out in his answer, you can use a timestamp as your seed and then hash it. This is called a UUID (Unique Universal Identifier, if it's a 128bit timestamp) is predictable, and can be bad for a number of reasons:

1. The accuracy to which you take this timestamp becomes the deciding factor of how predictable this salt is.
2. If you take the time in seconds as an integer and hash it, then you end up with very defined and easily guessed salts

Nevertheless, with enough accuracy, you can still use a timestamp as a *unique* salt. Not *random* (unless you use it as a random seed and base convert it to base10, which is still a bad idea). Consider this if you can count time in something under nanoseconds and fancy using it as a unique ID. PHP cannot feasibly process fast enough to give two colliding sub-nanosecond IDs<sup>1</sup> (but that doesn't mean you shouldn't verify!)

---

<sup>1: It works with composer!</sup>

Comment: what "bothers" me is that I have to store the salt separately when bcrypt stores it along with the hash, but I can't query all the rows, extract the salt from the hash and check previous usage!It's unproductive! Would it be a problem if out of thousands of users two share the same salt?

Comment: if you are using bcrypt, you dont actually need salts to be truly unique for password hashing. Having the same salt twice is just as random as having different salts, from a purely mathematical point of view. Also, that class i linked is used in real-world login systems, and beats the old ones (they were using unsalted sha1, *shudder*)

Comment: thank you! I was desperate to find a way to have unique salts while using bcrypt without storing to check them against each other!

Comment: I'll add this to the answer in case it helps future visitors

Answer (score 4):

This is the way I am doing sometime...

```
// chars
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@#$%^&*()-+';

// convert to array
$arr = str_split($chars, 1);

// shuffle the array
shuffle($arr);

// array to chars with 22 chars
echo substr(implode('', $arr), 0, 22);
```

Output

```
xd*thKM$B#13^)9!QkD@gU

ixXYL0GEHRf+SNn#gcJIq-

$0LruRlgpjv1XS8xZq)hwY

$G-MKXf@rI3hFwT4l9)j0u
```

To make sure it is unique, you can always check in your database. In case it is repeated re generated the KEY.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought of using shuffle; I just used the string as an array and randomly picked out chars based on numbers. +1.

Comment: @Madan Sapkota  Your method is similar to the one I use.  However,with your method each character will only appear once, and is hence much less random.  Try this instead.  It works great for me: `$pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, 22)), 0, 22);`

Answer (score 2):

You can check the answer of my own question. 
[How to generate Unique Order Id (just to show touser) with actual Order Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387755/how-to-generate-unique-order-id-just-to-show-touser-with-actual-order-id)

You can use **TimeStamp** instead of any random string.

Regarding your solution, there is possibility of collision, but its at very low level.

Answer (score 1):

You won't guarantee that this will always return a unique value, but it will minimize the risk significantly. There is ALWAYS a possibility of duplicates when you use a random number generating algorithm.

To guarantee that only unique values are generated you can search against previously generated values and discard duplicates.

Some suggestions to reduce the chances of duplicates in your formula:

- Don't use the `sha1`. This is a method that returns the one consistent output for any given input. It won't impact the possibility of duplicates.
- Instead of the `sha1`, consider converting the random number into a different base (for instance, numbers in base 36 can use the characters 0-9 and A-Z, which you can store in your database or whatever you're doing with the random string output). But I wouldn't really go for 36 here, maybe 256+?
- Since you're limiting the string to 22 characters with `substr` you're actually increasing the chances of duplicates a little. Use what I wrote about in the previous bullet to convert the random number to a string with fewer than 22 characters that does not need to be truncated.
- Also, you can remove the need for `substr` by returning a **raw** value with the `sha1` function, which is only 20 characters.
- Or, just dont limit the string to 22 characters (unless you really need to for whatever reason).

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the `time()` function.

I needed to do something similar, a solution to keep unique id and i ended up with a solution to use PHP function `time()` like this `$reference_number = 'BFF-' . time();` you can change the BFF to something that makes more sense to your business logic. This way i dont have to worry about if new id that is being generated was taken up before since time is always unique

I hope this helps